# 'DeltaMergeBuilder' object has no attribute 'WhenNotMatchedInsert'

Tags: databricks, upsert, delta-lake

while doing merge with deltatable getting below error.

'DeltaMergeBuilder' object has no attribute 'WhenNotMatchedInsert'

```py
from delta.tables import *
delta_df = DeltaTable.forPath(spark,"dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/FileStore/tables/stream_write2")

delta_df.alias("t").merge(
df.alias("s"),
"target.empid=source.empid").whenMatchedUpdate(set =
{
"name":"source.name",
"city":"source.city",
"country":"source.country",
"contactno":"source.contactno"
}
).WhenNotMatchedInsert(Values =
{
"empid":"source.empid",
"name":"source.name",
"city":"source.city",
"country":"source.country",
"contactno":"source.contactno"
}
)
.execute()
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'DeltaMergeBuilder' object has no attribute 'WhenNotMatchedInsert'

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3810732791373279> in <cell line: 1>()
1 delta_df.alias("t").merge(
2 df.alias("s"),
3 "target.empid=source.empid").whenMatchedUpdate(set =
4 {
5 "name":"source.name",

AttributeError: 'DeltaMergeBuilder' object has no attribute 'WhenNotMatchedInsert'
Command took 0.21 seconds -- byat 1/5/2023, 6:09:03 PM on Cluster
```

I am working on upsert in delta table but getting below error.

Comment: what version of databricks runtime is used?

Answer (score 1):

The error is simple - your function name is using upper case `W`, but it should be lower-case: `whenNotMatchedInsert`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was working on one  requirement to update and insert into two different delta tables upon landing of new file.Is it possible in databrciks or SQL in one statement.  like file -->delta table -->Table 1(only upsert data) & Table 2(for delete data)     Is it possible.